# wordpress xml generated data

Tags: xml, wordpress

I have to produce a site in WordPress fully based on XML data.

In the site I have to collect data on each and every link clicked by the user from third party.

Can I do this in WordPress?

If yes, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are asking and the question seems to broad and argumentative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below details/links for your ref:

[WordPress Web Service](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-web-service/)

[RESTful Web Services in a WordPress Plugin?](http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/restful-web-services-in-wordpress-plugin/)

[wordpress-web-service](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-web-service/)

Meanwhile, it would be better, if you could explain this question more better way with more details on your requirements.

Thanks !